# Probability distribution from moment-generating function?

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

The moment-generating function of $X\sim\chi^2(\nu)$ is given by
$$M_X(t)=(1-2t)^{-\nu/2}$$
for all $t<1/2$. For $\chi^2$ distribution, the degree of freedom $\nu$ is positive. Is it possible that the moment-generating function of some distribution looks like $M_X(t)$ but with a negative $\nu$? My guess is no, but how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try.  Say we have a random variable $Y$ such that
$$M_Y(t) = 1-2t.$$
What does this say about $Y$?  Well, we know that $$M'_Y(0) = \operatorname{E}[Y],$$ so $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = -2.$$  We also know that $$M''_Y(0) = \operatorname{E}[Y^2].$$  But that's $0$, and in fact, all higher moments are $0$.  How is this possible?  It would also imply
$$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - \operatorname{E}[Y]^2 = 0 - (-2)^2 = -4.$$  So no such variable exists.

Can we extend this reasoning further to the general case?  Try it:  let
$$M_Y(t) = (1-2t)^\nu, \quad \nu > 0.$$
(We can ignore the factor of $1/2$ in the exponent.)  What happens when you try to calculate $\operatorname{Var}[Y]$?